# Xcode 4.5 giving 'failed to get the task for process 3806' error

Tags: xcode, ipod

Recently, I wanted to test out my app. I don't exactly want to buy the Apple Certificate yet because I just want to test out my app. Though rest assure, I will buy the certificate once I am ready to sell my app on the App Store.

Anyways, I fake code signed xcode so I can test my app without a developer's certificate. Problem is, whenever I run my app, I get the error

```
failed to get the task for process ****
```

The **** is a random number each time.

On my iPod, the app launches but I get a black screen and then it returns to the springboard.

I am running iOS 5.1.1. I have changed the deployment target to 5.1 and to 5.0. I have also made sure I'm running the fake certificate. I also disabled autolayout.